# how to use ng-bind in a jquery function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#other_services{{i.id}}").css("display", "none");

  function other_services() {
    $("#other_services{{i.id}}").css("display", "block");
    $(".ser_o{{i.id}}").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

How the ng-bind in angular js will work in this code?

Comment: use ng-show and ng-hide for your context

Comment: what you want exactly?.

Comment: here **i** is one of the element in a list. I just want it's id in the script tag

Comment: Your application is based angularjs or jquery. Angularjs you can use $scope for bind, and use ng-class for apply your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code will not work. The ng-bind will help with in loop or with in scope controller in html. We have Jqlite in angular you can use it for basic jquery. If you want hide or apply css you can use ng-if, ng-hide and ng-class.

**ng-if**

```
<label>Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" /></label><br/>
```

Show when checked:

  This is removed when the checkbox is unchecked.

**ng-hide**

```
<div ng-hide="myValue" class="ng-hide"></div>
```

when $scope.myValue is false (element is visible)

```
<div ng-hide="myValue" ></div>
```

**ng-class**

```
<input id="setbtn" type="button" value="set" ng-click="myVar='my-class'">
<input id="clearbtn" type="button" value="clear" ng-click="myVar=''">
<span class="base-class" ng-class="myVar">Sample Text</span>
```